# Windows form apps how to add items from a list box

Tags: vba

I have an assignment to create a simple fast food ordering system, I managed to assign values to the items in the list box however each time I press the button to place an order it doesn't always add up the selected items.

```
Public Class FastFoodPizza
Dim cheesepizza, pepperonipizza, meatpizza, margheritapizza, bbqchickenpizza As Decimal
Dim thinbase, thickbase As Decimal
Dim large, medium, small As Decimal
Dim total As Decimal
Private Sub LtbPizzChoices_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ltbPizzChoices.SelectedIndexChanged

    ltbPizzChoices.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple


End Sub

Private Sub GrbBase_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grbBase.Enter

End Sub



Private Sub BtnPlaceorder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlaceorder.Click

    For Each item As String In ltbPizzChoices.SelectedItems
        If item = "Cheese Pizza" Then
            cheesepizza = 7.99

        End If
        If item = "Pepperoni Pizza" Then
            pepperonipizza = 8.99
            
        End If
        If item = "Meat Pizza" Then
            meatpizza = 9.49

        End If
        If item = "Margherita Pizza" Then
            margheritapizza = 7.49

        End If
        If item = "BBQ Chicken Pizza" Then
            bbqchickenpizza = 10.5

        End If
    Next


    txtTotal.Text = (cheesepizza + pepperonipizza + meatpizza + margheritapizza + bbqchickenpizza)

End Sub

Private Sub TxtTotal_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtTotal.TextChanged

End Sub
```

End Class[The image is of the design that of the windows app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jOE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we're here to do your homework for you, but ...

Your code is possibly going to set the value of `txtTotal.Text` to only the most recent selection rather than tally with previous selections (if this is your aim) because (guess) your list box is possibly set to single selection.

You (may) need to set a static or module variable to hold the individual selections and order total.

There're MANY ways to improve your code:

1. Create a Pizza class (Name, Price, Base, Size, properties, etc) and derive pizza types from it.
2. Use `Case Select` instead of multiple `If`s.
3. You have an empty `txtTotal.TextChanged` handler.

Etc.